# How to get the object id of the document in a mongodb collection during mongotemplate.save operation is executed?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, mongotemplate

Using MongoTemplate, I have saved a json in a collection. The objectid is generated automatically by MongoDB, I suppose.

How to get the objectid at the instant while saving?

```
mongotemplate.save(data,"collection");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you can do this, if Object "data" has field "id"

```
mongotemplate.save(data,"collection").getId();
```